# What is the best way to count adjacent edges by their name for each vertex?

Tags: arangodb, aql

I'm trying to count adjacent edges by their collection names.

For example, I have a vertex collection 'User' which has outbound edges to ['visited', 'add_to_cart', 'purchased'].

For each vertex user, I'd like to count adjacent edges by their collection names.

So the final return would be like

{
user_id : "user_1",
visit_count : 3,
add_to_cart_count : 5,
purchase_cnt : 1
}

I've tried the following query, but I doubt it makes the best performance as it uses if else condition and I guess it hinders the overall performance.

The query I tried :

```
FOR user IN User
   FOR v, e, p IN OUTBOUND user visited, add_to_cart, purchased
      COLLECT user_id = user.user_id
         AGGREGATE 
            visit_count = SUM(SPLIT(e._id, '/')[0] == 'visited'? 1 : 0),     
            add_to_cart_count = SUM(SPLIT(e._id, '/')[0] == 'add_to_cart'? 1 : 0),
            purchase_cnt = SUM(SPLIT(e._id, '/')[0] == 'purchased'? 1 : 0) 
     
      RETURN {
         user_id, visit_count, add_to_cart_count, purchase_cnt 
      }
```

If IT IS the best way, would there be any index-related gains I can get get use of?

Looking forward to your help :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to tobias from arangoDB community, I could make it about 30% faster.

```
LET vis = (FOR e IN visited COLLECT user_id = e._from WITH COUNT INTO n RETURN {user_id, visit_count: n})
LET cart = (FOR e IN add_to_cart COLLECT user_id = e._from WITH COUNT INTO n RETURN {user_id, add_to_cart_count: n})
LET purc = (FOR e IN purchased COLLECT user_id = e._from WITH COUNT INTO n RETURN {user_id, purchase_cnt: n})
FOR x IN UNION(vis, cart, purc)
COLLECT user_id = x.user_id AGGREGATE visit_count = SUM(x.visit_count), add_to_cart_count = SUM(x.add_to_cart_count), purchase_cnt = SUM(x.purchase_cnt)
RETURN {user_id, visit_count, add_to_cart_count, purchase_cnt}
```

The point he mentioned was to collect the edge collections directly!